# Bash if statement with AND

Tags: bash

Trying to figure out how to get working this condition, without using multiple if statement
Check if these files are in the folder, and basically if an integer is major then another, since i use to concat days hours and minute value of time to get two integers, one with current time and the other with schedule time.

```
FILE1=180.mp4
FILE2=360.mp4
FILE3=720.mp4
FILE4=1080.mp4
FILE5=audio.mp4

TIME=10155
SCHEDULE=20256

if [ test -f "$FILE1" ] && [ test -f "$FILE2" ] &&  [ test -f "$FILE3" ] && [ test -f "$FILE4" ] && [ test -f "$FILE5" ] && (( TIME > SCHEDULE )) ; then 
echo DO EVENT
else
echo DON'T DO EVENT
fi
```

Comment: You haven't asked an actual question. What problem are you having? If that's your actual code, then `echo DON'T DO EVENT` is a syntax error because the apostrophe character is a single quote. There are other problems in your code. If you're getting error messages, show them to us in the body of the question.

Comment: @MassimoVantaggio : The program which you have posted is not even syntactically valid, as you can see in your own posting, where the syntax highlighter of Stack Overflow paints your ìf` and `fi` in different colours .... What is it than you want to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` and `test` are synonyms. You should use one or the other, not both.

Alternative #1:

```
if test -f "$FILE1" && test -f "$FILE2" && test -f "$FILE3"  && test -f "$FILE4"  && test -f "$FILE5" && (( TIME > SCHEDULE ))
then 
  echo "true"
fi
```

Alternative #2:

```
if [ -f "$FILE1" ] && [ -f "$FILE2" ] && [ -f "$FILE3" ] && [ -f "$FILE4" ] && [ -f "$FILE5" ] && (( TIME > SCHEDULE ))
then 
  echo "true"
fi
```

However, like in any language, you'd be better off using an array:

```
files=(180.mp4 360.mp4 720.mp4 1080.mp4 audio.mp4)
if (( TIME > SCHEDULE ))
then
  for file in "${files[@]}"
  do
    if ! [ -f "$file" ]
    then
      echo "Missing $file" >&2
      exit 1
    fi
  done
  echo "Do the thing"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you will get a problem with the `echo DON'T DO EVENT`.  without quoting, you have a single-quote unmatched in that line.  The shell will likely issue `` unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' ``.

This should really be a comment, but I am still working on the rep points to be able to add comments